# How to hide TableSection in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Settings table with multiple TableSection under TableRoot:

```
<TableView HasUnevenRows="True" Intent="Settings">
        <TableRoot>               
            <TableSection Title="Sec1">
                <ViewCell> 
                    <StackLayout>
                        <!-- Items to show, based on value SHow/Hide Sec2-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
            <TableSection Title="Sec2">
                <ViewCell> 
                    <StackLayout x:Name="hideLayout">
                        <!-- Items to hide -->
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection> 
       </TableRoot>     
</TableView>
```

I'm not able to dynamically show or hide the TableSection as

- TableSection and ViewCell doesn't contain IsVisible property
- If `hideLayout.IsVisible = false;` is set, then there is empty space left in this place

Please provide any suggestion to implement.

Comment: you could set the height to 0 but thats kind of a hack ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview not updated when isVisible is set to true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718341/listview-not-updated-when-isvisible-is-set-to-true)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Its not duplicate of mentioned post. ListView contains IsVisible property but TableSection doesn't.

Comment: @FeDe TableSection doesn't have height property also. I tried using TableSection.Clear(), which will clear data but can not retrieve again. and still line below heading will appear.

Comment: Yes, but it's the same problem. Try to adapt the custom renderer. Important is that you call `Control.RelaodData()` after your Visibility property has changed.

Comment: Seeing my answer got deleted look at it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774368/how-do-i-hide-a-tablesection-with-xaml-in-xamarin-forms/39788469#39788469