# How do I hide a TableSection with XAML in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working in Xamarin Forms lately for a project, and I have been using the TableView to show details of a record retrieved from web api. Sometimes, certain details are not present, so I'd like to hide the section that displays the information.

However, I can't find a way to hide the TableSection.

Here's some XAML:

```
<TableView>
    <TableRoot>

        ...

        <!--Contact info-->
        <TableSection IsVisible="{Binding HasContact}" Title="Contact">

          <!--Contact name-->
          <TextCell Text="{Binding ContactName}" Detail="Primary contact" />

          <!--Phone-->
          <TextCell Text="Phone"
                    Detail="{Binding FormattedContactPhoneNumber}"
                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.DialPhoneCommand, Source={x:Reference MainGrid}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ContactPhoneNumber}"/>


          <!--Email-->
          <TextCell Text="Email"
                    Detail="{Binding ContactEmail}"
                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.SendEmailCommand, Source={x:Reference MainGrid}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ContactEmail}"/>

        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Obviously, the IsVisible property didn't work and throws an exception because it doesn't exist (It is present on other elements like Labels). I also tried using `VisualElement.IsVisible` which throws an invalid cast exception. So is there any way to hide this section?

If there isn't a way to do it, perhaps I'll need to go down a dirtier path and use separate TableViews (There I can use VisualElement.IsVisible) :(

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't worked with xamarin as much as I'd like but if it carries general xaml standards it would be `Visibility` property you would put your bool through a converter for to be either `Visible` or `Collapsed` as the param. ie; `Visibility="Collapsed"`

Comment: Thanks, however, Xamarin Forms uses their own custom controls, and the Visibility property is not available. Forms is translated into native controls at runtime.

Comment: Really? Well that's disappointing. Wonder if since MS bought them they might try to adopt some of the long standard conventions. Will have to tinker with xamarin more when I have time. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've hit the one drawback of using a TableView, not being able to hide sections dynamically through bindable properties.

In my project I solved this like so:

In the code behind of the page I listen for OnPropertyChanges of the ViewModel that is used as the BindingContext.
When the needed boolean changes, I Remove the Cell that is no longer needed in the TableSection.
When the Cell is needed again, I Insert it again.

So name all sections and cells and at page start get a hold of those cells that need to change for reference for removing and adding them later.

Small example code

```
private void OnViewmodelPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IsBioSecurityAvailable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        AdjustBioSecurityHeight();
    }
}

private void AdjustBioSecurityHeight()
{
    if (!_viewmodel.IsBioSecurityAvailable && GeneralSection.Contains(BioSecurityViewCell))
        GeneralSection.Remove(BioSecurityViewCell);
}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer. I'm actually going to go the route of bending a Grid to my will, but this is technically an answer.

Comment: Yeah not great that the control has no build in option